# get all post and comments on single html templates

Tags: jquery, python, html, ajax, django

I am quite new to django. So forgive me if any stupid content mentioned over here and please guide me.
I want to display the all post and related comments in to crave.html template. I tried that but am not able to do that. How can i use the ajax request over there?

models.py

```
class crave_data(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(User)
    post=models.TextField(blank = True,null = True)
    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)

 class comments(models.Model):

    crave=models.ForeignKey(crave_data, blank = True,null = True)
    reply=models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank = True,null = True)

    date= models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

i want to display the all possts and related comments on the crave.html page. And after submitting the craveit should get display on the same page. And there should be option for reply. Like normal post comment structure.
Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def crave_edit(request, id=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id) if id else None
    crave_made = None
    if instance and instance.person != request.user:
        raise PermissionDenied()

    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveDataForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
            crave_made = form.save(commit=False)
            crave_made.person = request.user
            crave_made.save()

       else:                    
        form=CraveDataForm(instance=instance)  

    return render(request, "crave/crave.html", {'form' : form,'crave_made':crave_made})


@login_required
def crave_view(request, id):
    #what id is this? this is crave_data id
    crave = get_object_or_404(crave_data, pk=id)
    print crave
    check = comments.objects.filter(crave=crave.id)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form=CraveReplyForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            reply = form.save(commit=False)
            reply.person=request.user
            reply.crave = crave
            reply.save()                    
    else:                    
        form=CraveReplyForm()  

    return render(request, "crave/comment.html", {'crave': crave, 'form' : form, 'check':check})
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('crave.views',
                       url(r'^$', 'crave_edit'),
                       url(r'^(?P<id>.*)/$', 'crave_edit'),
                       url(r'^reply_get/(?P<id>.*)$', 'crave_view'),

     )
```

crave.html

```
<form action="" method="post" style="font-size:150%">{% csrf_token %}
Query<br /><br/>
                {{ form.post }}
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" style="background-color:#53760D;color:#D0F18F;width:30% ;align:center;margin:0 auto;" />
</form>
```

comment.html

```
<form class="horizontal-form" role="form" action="/crave/reply_get/{{crave.id}}" method="post"  style="padding: 10px;">
           {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group" >
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                        {{ form.reply.label_tag }} {{ form.reply }} </br> </br>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="reply" />
    </form>
  {{crave}}
{% for pf in check%}
                  {{pf.reply}}<br>
            {% endfor %}
```

Rt now post and comment are on different templates. I want to use ajax request to get all post and comment on crave.html page.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance.